# Let $J⊆I⊆\Bbb R$ be open intervals, let $c∈J$, and let $f:I\setminus\{c\}→\Bbb R$ be a function.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions

Let J⊆I⊆$\Bbb R$ be open intervals, let $c∈J$, and let $f:I\setminus\{c\}→\Bbb R$ be a function.
Prove that  $\lim_{x \to c}⁡f(x)$ exists if and only if $\lim_{x→c}⁡f/_{J}(x)$ exists, and if these limits exist, then they are equal.

Comment: Use the fact that if $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n=c$, then there is $n_0$ such that $x_n\in J$ if $n\ge n_0$.

Comment: You just need to write the definitions carefully. This problem is not at all difficult.